# undefined method `read_bson_document' for BSON:Module

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bson

I'm trying to use this Ruby script:

```
require "bson"

def make_insert(table_name, bson)
  columns = ["id",*bson["value"].keys] * ", "
  values = ["'#{bson["_id"]}'",*bson["value"].values.map{|value| value.is_a?(Numeric) ? value : "'#{value}'"}] * ", "
  return "insert into #{table_name} (#{columns}) values (#{values});"
end

file_name = ARGV.first
file=File.new(file_name)
table_name=File.basename(file_name,".*")
while not file.eof? do
  bson = BSON.read_bson_document(file)
  STDOUT << make_insert(table_name,bson)
  STDOUT << "\n"
end
```

to convert data from bson to sql, the following error is been thrown : 
convertbson2sql.rb:13:in `<main>': undefined method`read_bson_document' for BSON:Module (NoMethodError)

I think that the method read_bson_document is no longer used in the new versions of the BSON library, I searched online and in the BSON library documentation but I couldn't figure out the replacement.

PS : I have nearly no knowledge in Ruby, I just want to use the script to convert my data.

Comment: What if you try with an older version of bson then?

Comment: Also, a question must include all necessary info in itself. No links to gist, etc.

Comment: thanks for replying, I tried with the version 1.11.1 using : sudo gem install bson -v 1.11.1.  but I still have the same problem . As I said I have no knowledge in Ruby so I don't know if it's the right way to change a library version.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've edited the question

Comment: The right way is to use [bundler](https://bundler.io/) to control what gem versions _exactly_ are to be loaded in your app/script.

Comment: "As I said I have no knowledge in Ruby" - would you be willing to learn some ruby? Or you just need to get the job done?

Comment: Helpful: https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#backwards-incompatible-changes-1

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I just need the job to get done maybe I'll learn some in my free time , anyway thanks I've unistalled BSON and reinstalled it with bundler and I no longer have this issue with bson. however I have now this problem : convertbson2sql.rb:4:in `make_insert': undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from convertbson2sql.rb:14:in `<main>'

Comment: "however I have now this problem" - yeah, something else is wrong. And maybe even more problems lie ahead. I suggest you take this job to a freelance site (or expert-for-hire site, like codementor/hackhands)

Comment: thanks the suggestions, I'm just following a symfony tutorial with a bson file to import the database so I'll look more for a solution to fill my  curiosity or use Mongodb instead of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but it does look like 2.0.0 had large scale changes [CHANGE LOG](https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Based on this you could try the following:

```
require 'bson'
require 'stringio'

stringio = StringIO.new
stringio.write File.read(file_name)
stringio.rewind
bson = BSON::Document.from_bson(stringio)
```

According to @SergioTulentsev the appropriate way may actually be:

```
bson = BSON::Document.from_bson(BSON::ByteBuffer.new(File.read(file_name)))
```

However this only works if each file is a single `BSON::Document`.

Comment: It's 4.3.0 now. Did they stop updating changelog at 3.2.6? :notlikethis:

Comment: modern way seems to be this: `BSON::Document.from_bson(BSON::ByteBuffer.new(str))`. The trick is how to split binary .bson file into document chunks.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev added your implementation as well. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but you changed my snippet. That line deserializes only one document. Will certainly not work on the whole file. In a couple of minutes I allotted for this experiment, I was not able to extract one document's byte chunk from the file stream. Hence my note.

Comment: JFYI, a spec which shows the usage: https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby/blob/27c1fee8bf5ce7c420bc0cc36f5e0c2eafe34ec9/spec/support/shared_examples.rb#L46-L59

Comment: And your version was true for 3.2: https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby/blob/3.2-stable/spec/support/shared_examples.rb#L54-L82

Comment: I see you didn't succeed as well. :) The answer (on how to properly split dump file) is probably very quickly found in the sources of `mongorestore`. Maybe some other time...

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I did not. When the documents are encoded the indicative character that proceeds the "document" changes based on the content of the document and I did not have enough time to bother investigating any further than this.